# Exclude some files from getting loaded while using a LOAD in Pig

Tags: file, hadoop, load, apache-pig, hdfs

I was trying to load output of a sqoop job into Pig via LOAD command. I only want files starting with name 'part' to be loaded. How can I exclude other files present in the same folder from getting loaded. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load like this, it will work

```
A = LOAD 'part*' using PigStorage(',');  
DUMP A;

Example:  
part_input.txt  
1,2,3  
4,5,6  

input.txt
99.0,55.0,56.3
12.4,55.66,78.09

output:
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: Hi, i want to load files which should not end with .tmp. Can you please help me how to do this.